# Python, can't parse element correctly

Tags: arrays, json, string, python-3.x, parsing

I'm just wondering if you could shine some light on this.

I'm using python3.6 and I'm trying to achieve the following two things here.

1. check if the success flag is true
2. only print the values to the screen as follows:

   ```
   Output:
   Bid:  XXXXXX
   Ask:  XXXXXX
   Last: XXXXXX
   ```

   Here is my code so far

   ```
   import sys
   import time
   import requests
   import json
   import os

   BTCtick = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc'
   reqBTC = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc').text
   BTCdata = json.loads(reqBTC)

   print(reqBTC)
   print(BTCdata['result'])
   exit()
   ```

Can somebody please tell me how to access the elements in that array or string or what it is? Please also explain if it is a string, or a query, array, so I understand why.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I still can't test for the success flag

```
    if (BTCdata['success'] == 'True'):
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")
```

But I found out it is a dictionary and if I want to access objects I can do it like this:

```
    print("Bid: ", BTCdata['result'] ['Bid'], sep='')
    print("Ask: ", BTCdata['result'] ['Ask'], sep='')
    print("Last: ", BTCdata['result'] ['Last'], sep='')
```